# Array of overlaping ranges

Tags: algorithms, trees, intervals

Consider that I have an array of ranges and I want to transform it to the new array that represents the ranges that any range is in.

## Example:

Ranges: 
[red: [1,11], black: [15,16],yellow: [5,9], green: [7,8]]

## Result:

- [1,4] - red
- [5,7] - red & yellow
- [7,8] - red & yellow & green
- [8,9] - red & yellow
- [10,11] - red
- [15,16] - black

My first thought was to use interval tree but the most implementations I found  want to ask tree by range and I want to explicitly list groups as shown in example.

Answer (score 2):

Sort all coordinates of intervals (annotated with their significance), and scan them in order.

As an example, in your case you would get
$$
1^{+red},5^{+yellow},7^{+green},8^{-green},9^{-yellow},11^{-red},15^{+black},16^{-black}
$$
This immediately gives the decomposition into intervals $$(1,5),(5,7),(7,8),(8,9),(9,11),(11,15),(15,16)$$
with associated colors.

Note that this list differs from your output, since you sometimes move the endpoint back by 1 point for some unspecified reason.